# How to use createContext in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There is an error in `React.createContext()` but when I declare an object `React.createContext({})` no error then.

> Mouse over "An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.
> function React.createContext(defaultValue: unknown): React.Context"

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

const AppContext = React.createContext(); `here is the error in createContext`

const AppProveider = ({ children }: any) => {
  return <AppContext.Provider value={{}}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};
export { AppContext, AppProveider };
```

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext#createcontext

Answer (score 2):

Hi that error is thrown by Typescript, meaning that the hook createContext need a defined type at his declaration.

Actually if u see in react package

```
  function createContext<T>(
     defaultValue: T,
  ): Context<T>;
```

As you can see the createContext Hook get a **Generic** which is assigned to a required property so without it ts will throw the error.

I spent some minute to implement a simple contex as example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntdd9y?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are encountering an error because of the React.createContext() function requires a default value to be passed as an argument. When you pass an empty object as the default value, the error goes away because you have provided a valid default value.

The error message you are seeing indicates that the defaultValue argument is missing when you use React.createContext(). To resolve this issue, you should provide a default value when creating the context.

Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

// Provide a default value for the context
const AppContext = React.createContext({});

const AppProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    return <AppContext.Provider value={{ /* your initial context value*/ 
  }}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```